# Path suddenly disappear when uniting with pathfinder

Tags: adobe-illustrator, pathfinder

I am having an issue with the unite tool of the pathfinder. It had been working flawlessly until now but suddenly some paths disappear after using it.

[Edit] : Merging produces the same result.

[Edit] : Expanding first, then uniting produces the same result.

Here is a [short clip](https://streamable.com/khoe94) showing the problem

I've tried googling but while some people had a similar issue none of the solutions worked for me thus far.

Am I doing something wrong, or perhaps it is a known issue, or am I using the unite tool for the wrong job?

**Current Solution** : Manually moving the paths into the folder.

Comment: Tried expanding first?

Comment: Unfortunately expanding first gives the same result.

Comment: I'm afraid without direct file examination, this may be tough to answer. You *may* have a compound path somewhere that is being used as the top object during the Unite function.

Comment: I have resigned myself to doing it manually and it does not really impact my workflow. I have a feeling the problem occurs after a certain number of paths is exceeded because when I started using a new color everything worked fine.



Here is the file if you would like to take a look at it : 

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1wz25aavhasfgU7egkQzANgV3fd5_vce5/view?usp=sharing

Comment: File is a mess of **open paths** with fills -- that is most likely the entire issue. I was going to close them to prove this, but I don't have the time to clean up the file. You need to close all paths for Pathfinder Unite to function correctly. It's **always** a bad idea to have open paths with a fill applied to them.

Comment: I had no idea that was the case, I will look into open paths and how to close them. I will give it a try and report back on results. Thank you for taking the time to look at it.

Comment: Unfortunately, open paths were not the cause : https://imgur.com/a/4Canko7

Comment: Well that's unfortunate. I don't have the time to close all the paths to further troubleshoot anything. I can **guess** ... there may be a no fill no stoke object on top.... there may be a compound shape on top that is causing the issue... again, just *guessing*. It has to be artwork related though, not a problem with overall functionality.

Comment: It is enough that you have explained to me that it is an issue with something I have done and not with the software itself. I posted the question thinking it may be a common problem with a known solution but I understand now it isn't. I have had no further issues in uniting my other strokes so all is well for me. Thank you for your time and have a great day !